# split lines by br tag and add in span tags

Tags: jquery

In a slideshow where the parent is `.cycle-slide` I'm struggling to get the following paragraph text example to go from this

```
<p>First line<br>leads to second<br>and then a third</p>
```

to this using javascript. I am trying to split the `p` by each `<br>` and then wrap the text in `<span>`

```
<p><span>First line</span><br><span>leads to second</span><br><span>and then a third</span></p>
```

I got this but it only shows in console.log()

```
jQuery('document').ready(function(){
    jQuery.each( jQuery( ".cycle-slide" ), function() {
        var data = jQuery(this).find('p').html().split('<br>');
        jQuery.each(data, function() {
            console.log(data);
            jQuery(data).wrap('<span>');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the `p` elements only contain `textNode`s and `br` elements, instead of splitting the `html` content and resetting the modified markup you can use the `.filter()` method for selecting the text childNodes and `.wrap()` method for wrapping the matched nodes.

```
// `.contents()` method returns childNodes of the selected elements
$('p').contents().filter(function() {
    // `nodeType` of the `textNode` is 3
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).wrap('<span/>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Ky7S/

Comment: wow, could you please explain what this is doing? what does return this.nodeType===3 do? how does it find the `<br/>`s

Answer (score 0):

You should update element's text..

```
     jQuery('document').ready(function(){
         jQuery.each( jQuery( ".cycle-slide" ), function() {
             var data = jQuery(this).find('p').html().split('<br>');
             jQuery.each(data, function() {
                 console.log(data);
                 this.text(jQuery(data).wrap('<span>'));
             });
         });
     });
```